# Ubuntu Server 12.04: How does one configure the firewall during installation?

Tags: firewall, ubuntu-12.04, kickstart, automated-install, ufw

I'm following [instructions](http://razvangavril.com/linux-administration/custom-ubuntu-server-iso/) to automate the installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 using kickstart. It works well for automatically partitioning the drives, selecting languages etc.  However, it doesn't configure the firewall. It is a [known issue](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html).

Running without a firewall isn't a good idea. How does one configure the UFW firewall during installation to prevent unauthorized access to the server?

The kickstart file I have looks as follows (with only the username changed)

```
#System language
lang en_US
#Language modules to install
langsupport en_US
#System keyboard
keyboard us
#System mouse
mouse
#System timezone
timezone America/Los_Angeles
#Root password
rootpw --disabled
#Initial user
user johnd --fullname "John Doe" --iscrypted --password <omitted>
#Reboot after installation
reboot
#Use text mode install
text
#Install OS instead of upgrade
install
#Use CDROM installation media
cdrom
#System bootloader configuration
bootloader --location=mbr 
#Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr yes
#Partition clearing information
clearpart --all --initlabel 
#Disk partitioning information
part / --fstype ext4 --size 1 --grow 
part swap --recommended 
#System authorization infomation
auth  --useshadow  --enablemd5 
#Network information
network --bootproto=dhcp --device=eth0
#Firewall configuration
firewall --enabled --trust=eth0 --ssh 
#Do not configure the X Window System
skipx
```

---

**UPDATE**

I added the following the file above:

```
%post
mkdir /usr/sample
ufw enable
ufw allow 22
```

After the installation, the directory `/usr/sample` exists, but the firewall is still disabled and access to port 22 isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the `%post` (post-installation) part of the kickstart file to run the firewall rules, or even create a basic firewall script.

I found, on this [site](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/6747/) an usage example of post-installation configuration.  And [here](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart#Chapter_5._Post-installation_Script) you have another explanation of how to achieve what you want.

**EDIT**: `%post` suggestion:

```
%post
mkdir /usr/sample
sed -i 's/^\(ENABLE=\s*\).*$/\1yes/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf
sed -i 's/^COMMIT/-A ufw-before-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT\n\nCOMMIT/' /etc/ufw/before.rules
ufw status verbose > /usr/sample/ufw_out.log
```

Try and see if this will work.  Maybe a little to over, but if this works, may be a nice workaround.

Comment: Tried it. Commands are executed, but calling UFW has no effect.

Comment: Can you post your file somewhere so I can see the entire picture? The known issue is that you can't configure firewall within the install... But the post-installation script you already have your system "ready".  Try activating UFW, or even passing some rules to the configuration file, through commands on `%post`.

Comment: I updated my question to include the %post section.

Comment: I did the same with my answer, reflecting the suggestion of changes to your `%post`.

Comment: Will give it a try. The first sed statement seems invalid. The second works. Since the ufw command line actually modifies   /lib/ufw/user6.rules and /lib/ufw/user.rules I'm going to replace those files and use sed to enable ufw.conf.

Comment: This worked for me to enable the firewall `sed -i 's/^\(ENABLED=\s*\).*$/\1yes/' /etc/ufw/ufw.conf`

Comment: You've helped me a bit. If you fix your answer, I'll mark this as answered.

Comment: Done editing the answer.